# PHP From with Captcha and email Validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a form @: http://www.shannonmoving.com/sendquote.php

As it stands, the user can just enter the captcha details and send the form empty.
I need it so the name and email address are required.

I setup spry validation, but the captcha code seems to bypass this.

Here's the PHP

```
<?php
if (($captcha_error == "on") && !isset($email)){
print("<div id=\"\" style=\"border: 1px solid #FFF; background: ##59A715; padding: 10px;\">There was a captcha error. Please go back and re-enter the captcha security code text.</div>");
$sent = "on";
} else

if (($_GET['send'] == "on")&&($captcha_error == "")) {

$message = "
____________________________

    CUSTOMER DETAILS
____________________________

FULL NAME:              $_POST[fullname]
EMAIL:                  $_POST[email]
PRIMARY PHONE:          $_POST[primaryphone]
SECONDARY PHONE:        $_POST[secondaryphone]
REFERRED BY:            $_POST[referredby]
PREFERRED MOVE DATE:    $_POST[preferredmovedate]
ALTERNATE MOVE DATE:    $_POST[alternatemovedate]
MOVING OUT OF:          $_POST[movingoutof]
MOVING INTO:            $_POST[movinginto]
PACKING REQUIRED:       $_POST[packing]

etc,etc


$name = "$_POST[First] $_POST[Last]";
$email = "$_POST[email]";


mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: $name <$email> \nX-Mailer:PHP/" . phpversion());
mail($to2, $subject, $message, "From: $name <$email> \nX-Mailer:PHP/" . phpversion());
mail($to3, $subject, $message, "From: $name <$email> \nX-Mailer:PHP/" . phpversion());
mail($to4, $subject, $message, "From: $name <$email> \nX-Mailer:PHP/" . phpversion());

?>

<div style="background: #24420F; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #FFF;">
Thank you for taking the time to fill out our online form it has been <br/>Successfully Sent!
</div>


<?php

$sent = "on";
} 


if ($sent == "") {
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute "required" on the name and email input elements (assuming html 5)

```
<input name="email" type="email" required/>
```

Comment: Cheers Jimmay, but it's not HTML5, so it's not working. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but can you try with change the first line :

```
if (($captcha_error == "on") && !isset($email)){
```

By

```
if (($captcha_error == "on") || !isset($email)){
```

Comment: Thanks Georgio, but that doesn't work, it just brings it directly to the error page. I appreciate it though.